# Adding element to Javascript object does not work using JSON format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have created a js object like this:

```
var JSONObject = {};
```

and a function a create an element an adds that to `JSONObject` :

```
function addShape(JSONObject, shapeStruct)
{
    var sh = "shape"+shapeStruct.id.toString();
    JSONObject.sh={
    "id": shapeStruct.id,
    "x1": shapeStruct.x1,
    "x2": shapeStruct.x2,
    "y1": shapeStruct.y1,
    "y2": shapeStruct.y2
    };
}
```

this function is in a separate file.

to call it i used:

```
shapeId++;
singleShapeStruct = {"id":shapeId, "x1":oldX, "x2":correctedX, "y1":oldY, "y2":yCanvas};
addShape(JSONObject, singleShapeStruct);
alert(JSONObject.shape0.x1);
```

the alert does not give any thing.

thanks for any kinf of help

Comment: FYI, there is nothing in your question or code that has anything to do with JSON. `{}` is an *object literal* here, which is a syntax construct to indicate an object. OTOH, JSON is a textual data-exchange format, like XML or CSV. See alse: [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: @FelixKling i have been confusing really between JSON concept and JS objects, thanks, but can we say that JSON spec. requires JS object when it’s used in a string context??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but I will add some more explanation: If you have a text file only containing, e.g. `["foo", "bar"]`, then you have JSON. If the file contains `var foo = ["foo", "bar"];`, then you have JavaScript creating an array. If you have `var foo = '["foo", "bar"]';` then you have JavaScript creating a string which contains data in JSON format. In JavaScript source code, JSON can only exist inside strings. You can parse such data to JS objects and arrays.

Comment: it's quiet clear @FelixKling, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign anything to `JSONObject.sh`, it won't use the variable `sh`. The name of the property will be `"sh"`, not the value of the variable `sh`.

To use the variable to name the property, use the bracket syntax:

```
JSONObject[sh] = ...
```

Comment: How can I parse it and get the "x1" value for example?

Comment: @abualbara: There is no parsing needed, as it's already in the form of an object. You would parse it if you had a JSON string that you needed to access as an object. To access properties of an object inside your object, you can either use the property name as `JSONObject.shape0.x1` or the bracket syntax `JSONObject["shape0"].x1`. You can of course use a variable to specify the string in the bracket syntax.

Comment: ooh thanks, I mean to get all object attributes: i used that: for(var i=0; i<Object.keys(JSONObject).length; i++) {
   console.log(Object.keys(JSONObject)[i]);
   console.log(JSONObject[Object.keys(JSONObject)[i]].x1);
  }

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a variable which has the actual key, you need to use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) instead of [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation) as the [member operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators)

```
function addShape(JSONObject, shapeStruct)
{
    var sh = "shape"+shapeStruct.id.toString();
    JSONObject[sh]={
    "id": shapeStruct.id,
    "x1": shapeStruct.x1,
    "x2": shapeStruct.x2,
    "y1": shapeStruct.y1,
    "y2": shapeStruct.y2
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the `JSONObject` doesn't contains the `sh` property.

you have to initialize the `JSONObject` `.sh` object as

```
JSONObject[sh] = 
{
    "id" : .....
    "x1" : .....
    .
}
```

using Square Bracket notation for variable value as a name (dynamic) .. Not by dot Operator.
dot operator requires static name of a property to be initialized.

Comment: *"dot operator of an object refers an existing property"* That is incorrect. `var foo = {}; foo.bar = 42;` works perfectly fine.

Comment: yea u are right. @FelixKling.. but here the property inside the object is not static name. constructing as `sh = "shape"+shapeStruct.id.toString()`. `foo.bar` is the static name, but `sh` is not.. am i right ?? I am sorry if i was Wrong....

Comment: Yes. If you want to use the value of a variable as property name, you have to use bracket notation. No worries, you can [edit] your answer and correct it :)